# Sharing text message from an iOS app to facebook

Tags: ios, iphone, facebook

I have a microblogging app for ios [developed by hiring freelancers]. It permits posting of text messages upto 147 characters only.

I wish that a user should be able to share a microblog from app to facebook.

But freelancer told me that Facebook doesn't permit so.

Is this correct? Does Facebook not allow text sharing?

If not correct, what is the possible workaround?

Comment: you can check this https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/ios

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sharing a message on Facebook is only possible by authorizing a user with the `publish_actions` permission. You need to get the permission reviewed by Facebook before everyone can use it. Without review, it will only work for users with a role in the App.

API reference and example code: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/feed#publish

Login Review: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/review

That being said, prefilling the message is not allowed, the user must write every single character on his own: https://developers.facebook.com/policy/

Easier solution without authorization: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/web

Answer (score 1):

In facebook sharing is possible. But facebook is not allowed share default text. when share text at a time open facebook dialog for enter text.
Refer : https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/ios

Answer (score 0):

Sharing is possible. You can check the following link https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/ios